# Converting spherical polar meshgrid to cartesian meshgrid

Tags: python, plotly

So I'm trying to make a 3D plot of atomic orbitals using plotly. Since the orbitals functions are spherical i tried to convert the spherical meshgrid into cartesian. what I noticed is the THETA(meshgrid) values are completely 0 and hence I dont see a plot. I reckon my understanding of how meshgrid works is not correct. Can someone tell me how to convert the spherical coordinates into a 3D cartesian plot.

Here is my code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
r=np.linspace(-1,1,30)
theta, phi = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 30), np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 30)
R, THETA, PHI = np.meshgrid(r, theta, phi)
X = R * np.sin(THETA) * np.cos(PHI)
Y = R * np.sin(THETA) * np.sin(PHI)
Z = R * np.cos(THETA)
# x=np.linspace(-1,1,30)
# y=np.linspace(-1,1,30)
# z=np.linspace(-1,1,30)
# X,Y,Z=np.meshgrid(x,y,z)
values =  np.exp(-R/2)*R*(np.cos(THETA))

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Volume(
    x=X.flatten(),
    y=Y.flatten(),
    z=Z.flatten(),
    value=values.flatten(),
    isomin=np.min(values),
    isomax=np.max(values),
    opacity=0.1, # needs to be small to see through all surfaces
    surface_count=21, # needs to be a large number for good volume rendering
    ))
fig.show()
```